# Novel about Bugs Bunny being tricked by a wealthy man to loot some snowy building

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

In my childhood, I bought a novel at a garage sale and read through it. This novel appeared to be official and even had professional illustrations of Bugs Bunny. It had the following plot points:

- Bugs Bunny saw a wealthy man throwing money out of his car, and a mob of people began collecting the money.
- Bugs Bunny wanted to be as generous as this wealthy man, to be able to be so rich as to throw money out of his car.
- So Bugs Bunny talked to the wealthy man.
- Wealthy man told Bugs Bunny his secret to his wealth: gold hidden in some snowy building! All Bugs Bunny has to do is go down to the snowy building and get the gold.
- Bugs Bunny left the house with a new purpose in life.
- Wealthy man reveals to the audience that he wasn't actually wealthy to begin with...instead, he is using what little money he has left to *pretend* to be rich, so that he could trick naive people into asking him where he got his money. Then the "wealthy man" can tell them to loot the gold from the snowy building, in the hopes that he can then intercept them, and then steal the gold from them (thereby actually being wealthy).
- Bugs Bunny does get the gold.
- "Wealthy man" tries to steal the gold, Bugs Bunny outwits him.
- Bugs Bunny converts the gold into cash and starts throwing the money out of his car too.
- The masses didn't bother collecting the dollar bills; they saw Bugs Bunny as not being "professional".
- Bugs Bunny didn't care. He wanted to be generous, and didn't care about people's reactions.

It had an interesting plot that I still "like", but can't recall its title or even what area Bugs Bunny was supposed to loot (other than the fact it's snowy).

I also remember, but am not 100% sure, that Bugs Bunny had a sidekick (Daffy Duck) as well.

Comment: So, just to be clear, as a "novel", this was primarily text with the occasional illustration?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Are you certain it was bugs bunny?

Comment: Yes, I am certain. If it wasn't Bugs Bunny, it wouldn't have been as rememberable, and I probably wouldn't have bought it at the garage sale.

Comment: What year you speculate it was? And where was the book bought?

Comment: I don't know the year of this book, but the quality of the book seems to me that it came from the 1990s-2000s. I bought the book at a garage sale, and I didn't inquire where the previous owner got it from.

Comment: are we closing this because bugs bunny is offtopic?

Comment: Because bugs bunny is cleary ontopic, so we must assume that this work is also probably ontopic. Bugs lives in a fantasy world were you can have an anvil fall from the sky and hit you in the head with little to no recorse.

Comment: @Himarm He doesn't live in a fantasy world, he lives in a kids' cartoon world. Pulling stuff out behind your back or out of thin air does not fantasy make, in the same way a talking animal doesn't.

Comment: child cartoons are off topic with just talking animals, children cartoons are immediatly on topic with said talking animals do something impossible, like put their rabbit hole in the sky. @CahirMawrDyffrynæpCeallach  and have micheal jordan, and bill murry play basketball with aliens

Comment: @Himarm Of course they're doing impossible crap, they're talking animals, shooting at each other and producing stuff out of nowhere. But I fail to see what's fantasy about that. They're not magicians, they just live in a simplified kids' cartoon world. An implausible story is as much fantasy as an acid trip is (hint: *not* much).

Comment: disney princes movies are just children movies as well, yet their all on topic

Comment: If Zootopia is on-topic, Bugs-Bunny is on-topic too

Comment: @himarm Most of those involve some form of magic or other explicit fantasy elements.

Comment: @RogueJedi but since magic and fantasy elements are common in bugs bunny, (see mos for pictures of bugs with dragons, witches, aliens) we must assume this work could be on topic and not close it till an answer is found,which may then end up being off topic

Comment: Possibly Bugs Bunny and Klondike Gold? Been a long time since I read it, but might be. Sidekick is Porky Pig, though.

Comment: I think that's correct (an Amazon reviewer mentioned the existence of a "hidden city", which I do remember was mentioned in the story as well...and  the Abebooks profile proved that the book itself appeared novel-like). I don't really know why I thought Daffy Duck was involved, but it's probably just misremembering. If you want to convert your comment into an answer, go right ahead.

Comment: @Aegon *Zootopia* has sepcifically been ruled on-topic because of its actual science-fiction plot, nothing else. It doesn't magically make Bugs Bunny on-topic.

Comment: @CahirMawrDyffrynæpCeallach These comments were made before Valorum's Meta Post I believe. Only advanced tech we saw there was the eco systems and the architecture.

Comment: @Himarm It's not off-topic because it's for children, it's off-topic because it doesn't actually have any fantasy elements other than being a simplified kids' story. Disney princess movies aren't on-topic because they're for kids, but because they contain fantasy crap.

Comment: I swear I've read this. Little golden or big Little books, maybe?