# Bugs Bunny picture book involving a machine that creates carrots

Tags: story-identification, books, childrens-novel, looney-tunes

I was suddenly struck with a memory of a Bugs Bunny book I read as a child (I probably read it in the 1980 to 1990 time frame, but I'm pretty sure it was a book that had been in the house for longer than that). Bugs had a machine that had a crank on the side, and turning the crank generated carrots. I think he had to feed something else in the hopper at the top, although I don't recall what, and what he fed into it influenced the carrots (what sticks in my head is the carrots being blue, or cubical, which later made me think it might have been a "square root" joke for the adults).

I don't recall where he got the machine. I think it wound up breaking down due to him either using it too much or trying to jam too much stuff in the hopper.

Comment: Aparently [we never discussed Bugs Bunny on Meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=bugs+bunny), but correct me if I'm wrong, I don't remember the animals having been lifted or whateves and the fantasy in that was mostly kids cartoon logic. From where I stand that's off-topic but correct me if I missed something...

Comment: @Jenayah: It came up at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135054/novel-about-bugs-bunny-being-tricked-by-a-wealthy-man-to-loot-some-snowy-buildin, but nevertheless, a machine that creates carrots from junk is pretty sci-fi. :)

Comment: Hmmm. Reading the comments there it seems we could go into the same round of arguments... As for the machine, from where I stand that's kind of the same 'kid's cartoon logic" stuff than the anvil. I'm itching to press the close button on that other one too, but better to take it to Meta instead.

Comment: [Here goes the Meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12319/98028)

Comment: If Donald Duck is on-topic as per https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/204827/donald-duck-almost-burns-down-his-house-trying-to-bake-something then Bugs must be as well?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## [*Bugs Bunny's Carrot Machine*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1646195.Bugs_Bunny_s_Carrot_Machine) (1971)

Here is a picture of the machine and Bugs putting junk in to get it to work.

[image: Pages showing the machine in action]

And the machine does eventually <s>break down</s> explode due to Bugs being too greedy and shoving too much junk into it as shown above.

[image: Pages showing the machine exploding]

The whole thing is being shown in this YouTube video:

Comment: Thank you. I realized it right after posting the question and doing an elementary Google search. :-D But you beat me to it. Apropos username too.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I approve of the machine and any chance to answer these sorts of questions.

Comment: Fulfilling the carrot responsibilities  +1

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Any idea what he puts in the machine to create lethal carrots?

Comment: @LordFarquaad Strychnine of course...